# How to display records in table with top 10 enteries with specific colour

Tags: php, html, css, sql

I an trying to display records in table with top 10 enteries with specific color

My Query just for Ref.

```
$sqlsum=mysql_query("SELECT `userid`, SUM(`points`) as `total` FROM 
    `tablename` GROUP BY `userid` ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10");
```

This code below displays a simple table, I need to display table With TOP 10 entries be different in colour[blue].. rest remains the same [white background].
i.e Top 10 can be in  blue color, and rest in white color.
Below is the code I am using to display records.

```
<?php 

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlsum)) 
      {
echo "<tr> ";
     echo "<td>" .$row[userid] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" .$row[total] . "</td>";
     }

echo "</tr> " ;
      ?>
```

I have this table structure as sample. That I want to use, with this code. The table need to be the same , but i am not to find the logic , how to build the table
  with this structure

```
     <table>
    <thead><tr><td colspan="2"><center>Prizes</center></td></tr><tr>
<th>Position</center></th><th><center>Prize</center></th></tr></thead>
    <tbody><tr><td>1st</td><td>0.0$</td></tr>
    <tr class="alt"><td>2nd</td><td>0.0$</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3rd</td><td>0.0$</td></tr>
    <tr class="alt"><td>4th</td><td>0.0$</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5th</td><td>0.0$</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: try to add style to all <td> and <th>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove Limit 10 For Fetch All Data:

```
$sqlsum=mysql_query("SELECT `userid`, SUM(`points`) as `total` FROM 
 `tablename` GROUP BY `userid` ORDER BY total DESC");
```

php:

```
<?php 

$i=1;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlsum))
{
     echo "<tr ".(($i <= 10) ? "bgcolor='blue'" : '')'."> "; 
     // Apply attrinute bgcolor for backgroung color
     echo "<td>" .$row[userid] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" .$row[total] . "</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     $i++;
}

?>
```

Comment: Error is appearing on line :  echo "<tr ".(($i <= 10) ? "bgcolor='blue'" : '')'."> "; 

Error::::

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''."> "; ' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Use this ---> echo "<tr ".(($i <= 10) ? "bgcolor='blue'" : '')."> ";

Answer (score 0):

Set an indicator variable to point it.

```
<?php 

      $rowNumber = 0;
      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sqlsum)) 
      {
         if ($rowNumber < 10)
         {
             echo "<tr class=\"alt\"> ";
         }
         else
         {
             echo "<tr> ";
         }

         echo "<td>" .$row[userid] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" .$row[total] . "</td>";
         echo "</tr> " ;

         $rowNumber++;
     }

?>
```

Comment: does not work, out is similar to the code i am using